# consolidatedAnnotation attribute is null error from AWS SageMaker Ground Truth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have used AWS SageMaker Ground Truth to annotate an image using Mechanical Turk.

The labelling job failed with the following error in the output manifest:

```
{"source-ref":"<MYIMAGE>","Test1-ref-metadata":{"retry-count":1,"failure-reason":"Error in Annotation Consolidation Response :  consolidatedAnnotation attribute is null","human-annotated":"true"}}
```

Does anyone have an idea if this is a bug or if I made a mistake?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using SageMaker Ground Truth. Sorry to hear you are having issues. Please post your question in the AWS Developer forum for SageMaker, in order for us to help you out as we need some additional information to help. AWS forums have the ability to send private messages to verified AWS engineers who can look up your Ground Truth LabelingJob.

Here is the forum link for your convenience: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=285